# EBX Relative references are not recognized by ghidra

Tags: ghidra, pie

String references are not recognized by ghidra on PIC .so file

The calls are calculated by a relative offset from the EBX register.

1. On entry to the function, EBX is set
2. relative offset is added (for example : ADD EBX ,0x176a07)
3. then relative calls to strings/functionsis not being detected

[image]

And:

[image]

How can i fix this?